# Expectation of sample median, general uniform case

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Intuitively obviously, the expectation of the median of sample taken from a $Uniform[a,b]$ distribution is simply $\frac12(b-a)$ but I'm having trouble proving that this is the case. I've shown it for the case $Uniform[0,1]$ and I done that by using the formula for the pmf of the order statistics to find the expectations for them.

Comment: If $X\sim U(a,b)$, then $\frac{X-a}{b-a}\sim U(0,1)$.

Comment: And the expectation of sample median is $\frac12(b+a)$, not $\frac12(b-a)$.